# Smooth linestring shapefile

Tags: python, shapely, linestring, smoothing

Is there an algorithm to perform a smoothing of a linestring and maintain the original points?

Comment: smoothing and maintaining the original points is impossible, the act of smoothing must move the points?

Comment: All the nodes of the original line or just the start and end node?

Answer (score 4):

If you use shapely, you can try [the `simplify(tolerance)` method](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.simplify) on LineString objects, which is based on the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

It's more of a simplifying algorithm than a smoothing one; but sometimes simpler linestrings happen to be smoother. Give it a try.